# R: autopopulation of data and date complements in a date sequence?

Tags: r, auto-populate, auto-populating

I am trying to autopopulate data. I need a command to fill the gaps between dates: *Intended Output* shows the gaps with similar precedence fills. The filling requires to fill the missing date entries.

**In R, how to autopopulate the data by filling the gaps between dates in some date sequence?**

---

*Minimal working examples*

**Input** for the dates sequence (2016-12-25, 2017-01-05)

```
> aa<- data.frame(a=c(1,11,111),b=c(2,22,222),length=c(3,5,1),date=c(as.Date("28.12.2016",format="%d.%m.%Y"), as.Date("30.12.2016",format="%d.%m.%Y"), as.Date("01.01.2017",format="%d.%m.%Y")))
> 
> dateSeq<-seq.Date(as.Date("2016/12/25"), as.Date("2017/01/05"), "day")
> dateSeq
 [1] "2016-12-25" "2016-12-26" "2016-12-27" "2016-12-28" "2016-12-29"
 [6] "2016-12-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03"
[11] "2017-01-04" "2017-01-05"

>
> aa
    a   b length       date
1   1   2      3 2016-12-28
2  11  22      5 2016-12-30
3 111 222      1 2017-01-01
```

that shows the data recorded. The NA-fills, [shown to some extent by Joel Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41362571/7301559), is done such that

```
dateSeq<-seq.Date(as.Date("2016/12/25"), as.Date("2017/01/05"), "day")
df<-data.frame(dateSeq)
df$date = as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
merge(df, aa, by = "date", all.x= TRUE)
     a   b       length  date
0.1  NA  NA      NA      2016-12-25
0.2  NA  NA      NA      2016-12-26
0.3  NA  NA      NA      2016-12-27
1    1   2       3       2016-12-28
0.4  NA  NA      NA      2016-12-29
2    11  22      5       2016-12-30
0.5  NA  NA      NA      2016-12-31
3    111 222     1       2017-01-01
0.6  NA  NA      NA      2017-01-02
0.7  NA  NA      NA      2017-01-03
0.8  NA  NA      NA      2017-01-04
0.9  NA  NA      NA      2017-01-05
0.10 NA  NA      NA      2017-01-06
```

where our goal is to fill the NA entries with something called `similar precedence` approach that depends on its neighbours.

**Intended Output** with the input date-complemented and similar precedence fills

```
     a   b       length  date
0.1  0.9 2       3       2016-12-25
0.2  1   2.1     2       2016-12-26
0.3  0.8 2.2     3       2016-12-27
1    1   2       3       2016-12-28
0.4  10  20      4       2016-12-29
2    11  22      5       2016-12-30
0.5  80  150     3       2016-12-31
3    111 222     1       2017-01-01
0.6  100 130     5       2017-01-02
0.7  50  200     3       2017-01-03
0.8  20  100     2       2017-01-04
0.9  14  40      5       2017-01-05
0.10 80  140     4       2017-01-06
```

Comment: all that you need to do is merge to get firstintended output

Comment: huh?... how did you get the values for `a`, `b` and `length`?

Comment: @Sotos by `similar precedence` approach where values similar to its neighbours,  I originally used LOCF (last observation carried forward) but now trying to find better alternatives to filling.

Comment: is there a function or any constrains to define your requirements of `similar precedence`?

Comment: @Sotos no, I try to find method that is somewhat close to the values around it: moving average models, auto-regression models and ARIMA models could be some approaches where the data is assumed to act as time-series. I have no idea whether they are implemented to R for this kind of case.

Comment: but you only have 1 value for each var to begin with. How are you going to forecast then?

Comment: @Sotos for example by moving averages: 2017-01-02 depends on all of its precedent values where the closest, 2017-01-01, affects it most. Values such as 3 (2016-12-28), 5 (2016-12-30) and 1 (2017-01-01) affect it. The values bteween 2016-12-25 and 2016-12-27 cannot be forecasted by the precedent values but we can estimate the moving averages over the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My point was:

```
dateSeq<-seq.Date(as.Date("2016/12/25"), as.Date("2017/01/05"), "day")
df<-data.frame(dateSeq)
df
#          date
# 1: 2016-12-25
# 2: 2016-12-26
# 3: 2016-12-27
# 4: 2016-12-28
# 5: 2016-12-29
# 6: 2016-12-30
# 7: 2016-12-31
# 8: 2017-01-01
# 9: 2017-01-02
#10: 2017-01-03
#11: 2017-01-04
#12: 2017-01-05
#13: 2017-01-06

df$date = as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
merge(df, aa, by = "date", all.x= TRUE)
#          date   a   b length
# 1: 2016-12-25  NA  NA     NA
# 2: 2016-12-26  NA  NA     NA
# 3: 2016-12-27  NA  NA     NA
# 4: 2016-12-28   1   2      3
# 5: 2016-12-29  NA  NA     NA
# 6: 2016-12-30  11  22      5
# 7: 2016-12-31  NA  NA     NA
# 8: 2017-01-01 111 222      1
# 9: 2017-01-02  NA  NA     NA
#10: 2017-01-03  NA  NA     NA
#11: 2017-01-04  NA  NA     NA
#12: 2017-01-05  NA  NA     NA
#13: 2017-01-06  NA  NA     NA
```

Comment: Good point +1, this is for the *1. Intended Output* so the autopopulation of the *2. Intended Output* is still missing.

Comment: i'm unclear about how you have filled the data actually, so I can't move forward